# How do I change a websites description on Google?

Tags: html, metadata, google-search

So, I have a web application and for some reason on Google the websites description is:

> No forwarding set for *sitename.com*.

How can I change this description?

Here's a screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w32yb.jpg

Comment: what the domain control panel are you using ?

Comment: Aplus.net is the DNS provider

Answer (score 7):

You can try to set a `meta name="description"`tag in the `head`of your website.

Example :

```
<meta name="description" content="This is an example of a meta description.">
```

However, it won't always be used, Google will decide wether or not it's appropriate to use the user defined description instead of the on-page content.

> The description attribute within the  tag is a good way to provide a concise, human-readable summary of each page’s content. Google will sometimes use the meta description of a page in search results snippets, if we think it gives users a more accurate description than would be possible purely from the on-page content.

Source : [Google webmaster](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en#1)

Comment: Thanks, will give this a shot! I presume it'll take some time to take affect even if they do chose to use the user defined description right?

Comment: Yes, you have to wait for Google to look at your website again. The pace at which it updates it is different from website to website and is dependant on many factors.